# Function username_exists() can't be accessed without logging in to wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the following function in `functions.php` to check if a username exists in the DB

```
function check_username() {
   $username = $_POST['user'];
   if ( username_exists( $username ) ) {
       $return['user_exists'] = true; 
   }
   else {
       $return['user_exists'] = false;
   }
   echo json_encode($return);
   die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_check_username', 'check_username');
```

The problem is that the `username_exists()` function only seems to work if a user is already logged in and checks a username. I tried to check for an existing username without logging in and it just returns `undefined` for me.

I have no idea why this is happening and can't find any documentation about this issue.

My question is, how do I enable a user to check if a user exists without having to log in?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
  function check_username() {
        $username = $_POST['user'];
         if ( username_exists( $username ) ) {
             $return['user_exists'] = true; 
         }
         else {
             $return['user_exists'] = false;
         }
         echo json_encode($return);
         die();
      }
      add_action('wp_ajax_check_username', 'check_username');
      add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_check_username', 'check_username' );
```

**wp_ajax_check_username** - anonymous / non-logged in visitors

**wp_ajax_nopriv_check_username**- logged in users